# How to avoid unneeded recompilation from IntelliJ Idea 13 when it runs a maven vaadin project created in the command line

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have created a maven vaadin project using the command line like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=7.1.9
```

Then I change into the folder of the application and I give at the command line the following :

```
mvn install
```

After waiting for the application to compile, I open it using IntelliJ Idea (by opening the pom.xml file), I add Tomcat Server and I press run.
Then the IntelliJ Ide recompiles the application again.
Is there any way I can avoid this second compilation?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes -- don't do the mvn install on the command line!

Comment: I am getting some errors when I use IntelliJ Idea 13 , so I decided to use the command line.

Comment: You should get the same results on the command line and in IntelliJ. If you're getting errors in intellij then you should probably fix the configuration so that you don't. You should not have to leave the IDE for simple things like building your project, deploying it to servers, etc. If you do then you're loosing out on a lot of the benefits of the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have tomcat configured as a server, and configure your module(s) to deploy at server startup. On the run configuration you will see a list of things to do before launch. It will probably say Make -- you can remove this if you need to.

However, you probably should allow idea to do this for you and really stop doing it on the command line. Idea can handle more complex build patterns for you. You should trust it.

Comment: I've let IntelliJ Idea 13 do all the work for me and it worked.I have forgotten to comment out the vaadin-client-compiler in the pom.xml file.